# Renaming the "Delete" button in edit mode of tableviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Can we rename the "Delete" button when put a table view in edit mode to something else?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The UITableView delegate just has to implement:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 5):

Implement

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And return your custom title for delete.

From [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) docs

Answer (score 1):

In Swift:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> String? {
        return "Remove"
    }
```

Comment: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> String?` in Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
*- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return @"Rename"; // or put something else
}*
```